# Rubio's weird E-mail

Tags: rhyme, steganography

So I woke up this morning to find a most peculiar e-mail from Rubio. It went like this:

```
      Skip and hop throughout the land, 
      every other is far too bland.
      Every fourth is far too grand,
      to skip and hop within this land.

 The hare was no hero. However, driving she and guards escape the pallid app. 

 Come with low ages erotic in odd leaf. 

 All suffer on tram corral estate. 

 Tiring nugget arm not daisy morals. 

 Oval iron log puppy. 

 Use zigzag likeness.
```

What was he trying to tell me?

Comment: The text layout (the first 4 lines tabbed) is relevant?

Comment: Man. I have ***got*** to do something about these blackouts I keep having.

Comment: @lois6b No, just for legibility

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to

> take every third letter

when we do so we get

> The shower is a great plaCe to get ideAs for creaTing and solving pUzzles

Comment: I figured this would get solved quickly :P

Comment: **My name is Rubio, and I approve this message.**